# JWT. Why is it better than oAuth and what's the signature?

Tags: jwt

I'm reading about JWT and I'm confused about why there's a signature:

[JWT site](https://jwt.io/)

What is the purpose of the signature if it's just a hashed version of the header and payload?

Also, why not just use oAuth? Or whatever 2  factor auth uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of Oauth2 and JWT is different, so it is not possible to compare them directly

- **JWT** is a compact way of representing claims to be transferred between two parties (JSON with digital signature).
- **OAuth2** is an authorization framework used by third party applications (websites, mobile apps) to access on resources on a resource server, without exposing user password.  **OAuth2 can use JWT as the exchanged token**

JWT is **self contained and does not need server sessions** . The digital signature is performed with server private key and protects the content. Any alteration of the header, the payload or the signature will be detected by the server and reject the token.